# How to create an image which keeps on rotating dynamically?

Tags: rotation

[image]

Hi, I am trying to create such rotating image? Can you tell how it is done?

Comment: If you provide us more details and/or bigger image maybe we will be able to help you

Comment: Please read [Important information for asking "What's this effect?" questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions) and edit this post accordingly. Make sure to use a descriptive title, too. Thank you!

Comment: *an image which keeps on rotating*: That's not an image, it's a series of images displayed in sequence, aka a movie.

Answer (score 4):

Some companies choose to render such images on computer instead of actually photographing and composing then in an animation.

If we are to talk **ONLY** about photographic processes, one would place the object on a rotating plate.
The rotation of the plate should be controllable on a degree level.
Then start photographing.

1. Initial position, Photo 1
2. Rotate a certain amount of degrees (let's call it Position 2), take second photo.

Continue the process rotating the object with the same amount of degrees till you get the object back in the initial position.
The smaller the rotation between the stops, the smoother the rotation will appear in the animation.

Get all the pictures in an image processing software and combine them into an [animated GIF](http://www.creativetechs.com/tipsblog/build-animated-gifs-in-photoshop/) or in a short movie clip (how to create a movie clip is not anymore a subject to be discussed on this website, you could try http://video.stackexchange.com).